# Given that $H = \frac{n^2}{\sigma(q^k)/2} = G \times J^2$, where $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number, then what is the value of $\gcd(G, J)$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, divisors-multiples, perfect-numbers

Let $N = q^k n^2$ be an odd perfect number with *special prime* $q$ satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.  Denote the *classical sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$ by $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$.

By the definition of a *perfect number* $N$, we have $\sigma(N)=2N$.  Since $\gcd(q,n)=1$ and because the divisor sum $\sigma$ is a multiplicative function, it follows that
$$\sigma(q^k)\sigma(n^2)=\sigma(q^k n^2)=\sigma(N)=2N=2 q^k n^2.$$

Now, just like when solving equations in terms of one variable, one should solve the equality
$$\sigma(q^k)\sigma(n^2)=2 q^k n^2$$
in terms of one of the expressions.

If one solves for $n$, that introduces a square-root, and takes one out of the integers.  If one solves for $q$, it introduces a $k$th root, and also takes one out of the integers.  One should not solve for $\sigma(q^k)$, since that quantity can already be re-expressed in terms of $q$ and $k$ as
$$\sigma(q^k)=\frac{q^{k+1} - 1}{q - 1},$$
if needed.  So, the more natural quantity to solve for is $\sigma(n^2)$.

Indeed, throughout [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.08116), we implicitly rely on the simple equality
$$\sigma(n^2) = \frac{2q^k n^2}{\sigma(q^k)}. \tag{1}$$
Unfortunately, this seems to introduce fractions.  To avoid that, we can use prime factorizations, as follows.  Write the prime factorization of $n$ as
$$n = {p_1}^{a_1} \cdots {p_m}^{a_m},$$
for some unique odd primes $3 \leq p_1 < \ldots < p_m$, and for some positive integer exponents $a_1, \ldots, a_m$.  Since both sides of $(1)$ are integers, and since $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ with $q$ prime, we know that
$$\sigma(q^k) = 2 {p_1}^{b_1} \cdots {p_m}^{b_m}$$
for some nonnegative integers $0 \leq b_i \leq 2a_i$.  Thus, we have
$$\sigma(n^2) = q^k {p_1}^{2a_1 - b_1} \cdots {p_m}^{2a_m - b_m}.$$

Note that the only other facts about odd perfect numbers that we use in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.08116) are that $b_i < 2a_i$ for at least one index $i$, and that $q$ is different from the $p_i$'s.

---

With this information, we immediately see that
$$G := \gcd\left(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2)\right) = \gcd\left(2 {p_1}^{b_1} \cdots {p_m}^{b_m},q^k {p_1}^{2a_1 - b_1} \cdots {p_m}^{2a_m - b_m}\right)$$
$$= {p_1}^{\min(b_1,2a_1 - b_1)} \cdots {p_m}^{\min(b_m,2a_m - b_m)},$$
$$H := \gcd\left(n^2,\sigma(n^2)\right) = \gcd\left({p_1}^{2a_1} \cdots {p_m}^{2a_m}, q^k {p_1}^{2a_1 - b_1} \cdots {p_m}^{2a_m - b_m}\right)$$
$$= {p_1}^{2a_1 - b_1} \cdots {p_m}^{2a_m - b_m},$$
and
$$I := \gcd\left(n,\sigma(n^2)\right) = \gcd\left({p_1}^{a_1} \cdots {p_m}^{a_m}, q^k {p_1}^{2a_1 - b_1} \cdots {p_m}^{2a_m - b_m}\right)$$
$$= {p_1}^{\min(a_1,2a_1 - b_1)} \cdots {p_m}^{\min(a_m,2a_m - b_m)}.$$

---

Here is our:

> **QUESTION:** What is the (simplified) prime factorization for $\gcd(G,J)$, where
> $$G = \gcd\left(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2)\right) = \gcd\left(2 {p_1}^{b_1} \cdots {p_m}^{b_m},q^k {p_1}^{2a_1 - b_1} \cdots {p_m}^{2a_m - b_m}\right)$$
> $$= {p_1}^{\min(b_1,2a_1 - b_1)} \cdots {p_m}^{\min(b_m,2a_m - b_m)},$$
> and
> $$J = \frac{H}{I} = \frac{I}{G} = \frac{n}{\gcd\left(\sigma(q^k)/2,n\right)}?$$

(Note that we have the identity $H = G \times J^2$.)

---

**OUR ATTEMPT**

We realized that, since the prime factorizations for $H$ and $I$ are given as follows:
$$H = {p_1}^{2a_1 - b_1} \cdots {p_m}^{2a_m - b_m}$$
and
$$I = {p_1}^{\min(a_1,2a_1 - b_1)} \cdots {p_m}^{\min(a_m,2a_m - b_m)},$$
then we have
$$J = \frac{H}{I} = \frac{n}{\gcd\left(\sigma(q^k)/2,n\right)} = \frac{{p_1}^{2a_1 - b_1} \cdots {p_m}^{2a_m - b_m}}{{p_1}^{\min(a_1,2a_1 - b_1)} \cdots {p_m}^{\min(a_m,2a_m - b_m)}}$$
$$= {p_1}^{2a_1 - b_1 - \min(a_1,2a_1 - b_1)} \cdots {p_m}^{2a_m - b_m - \min(a_m,2a_m - b_m)}.$$
Therefore, we have
$$\gcd\left(G,J\right)=\gcd\left({p_1}^{\min(b_1,2a_1 - b_1)} \cdots {p_m}^{\min(b_m,2a_m - b_m)},{p_1}^{2a_1 - b_1 - \min(a_1,2a_1 - b_1)} \cdots {p_m}^{2a_m - b_m - \min(a_m,2a_m - b_m)}\right)$$
$$={p_1}^{\min\left(\min(b_1,2a_1 - b_1),2a_1 - b_1 - \min(a_1,2a_1 - b_1)\right)} \cdots {p_m}^{\min\left(\min(b_m,2a_m - b_m),2a_m - b_m - \min(a_m,2a_m - b_m)\right)}.$$

We guess it all boils down to evaluating
$$\min\left(\min(b,2a - b),2a - b - \min(a,2a - b)\right)$$
for *arbitrary integers* $a$ and $b$.  **Alas, this is where we get stuck!**

We do know that
$$\min(b,2a-b) + 2a-b = 2\min(a,2a-b)$$
holds; however, this does not seem to help in this scenario.

Comment: I tried asking [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=FullSimplify%5Bmin%28min%28b%2C2a-b%29%2C2a-b-min%28a%2C2a-b%29%29%5D), it asserts that
$$\min\left(\min(b,2a-b),2a-b-\min(a,2a-b)\right)=\min\left(2a-b,b,2a-b-\min(a,2a-b)\right).$$

Comment: If we were to **believe** WolframAlpha, then this means that
$$\min\left(\min(b,2a-b),2a-b-\min(a,2a-b)\right)=\min\left(2a-b,b,2a-b-\min(a,2a-b)\right)=\min\left(b,2a-b-\min(a,2a-b)\right).$$

Comment: This [ProofWiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Min_Operation_is_Associative) page asserts that the $\min()$ function is **associative**, thus justifying WolframAlpha's computation above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is a partial answer, which uses the ideas in my earlier comments.**

---

We compute
$$\gcd(G,J)={p_1}^{\min\left(\min(b_1,2a_1 - b_1),2a_1 - b_1 - \min(a_1,2a_1 - b_1)\right)} \cdots {p_m}^{\min\left(\min(b_m,2a_m - b_m),2a_m - b_m - \min(a_m,2a_m - b_m)\right)}$$
$$={p_1}^{\min\left(2a_1 - b_1,b_1,2a_1 - b_1 - \min(a_1,2a_1 - b_1)\right)} \cdots {p_m}^{\min\left(2a_m - b_m,b_m,2a_m - b_m - \min(a_m,2a_m - b_m)\right)}$$
$$={p_1}^{\min\left(b_1,\min(2a_1 - b_1,2a_1 - b_1 - \min(a_1,2a_1 - b_1))\right)} \cdots {p_m}^{\min\left(b_m,\min(2a_m - b_m,2a_m - b_m - \min(a_m,2a_m - b_m))\right)}$$
$$={p_1}^{\min\left(b_1,2a_1 - b_1 - \min(a_1,2a_1 - b_1)\right)} \cdots {p_m}^{\min\left(b_m,2a_m - b_m - \min(a_m,2a_m - b_m)\right)}.$$

**Alas!  This is the furthest I could go with this technique.**